# 3D matrix multiplication using np.einsum

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to calculate the matrix multiplication of a 3D Matrix with dimensions corresponding to `(time, variable, space)`.

```py
# time, variable, space
M_np = np.random.random((100, 64, 50))

np.matmul(M_np, M_np.transpose(0, 2, 1)).shape
```

Returns

```
(100, 64, 64)
```

But when I try to calculate the same multiplication using `np.einsum`

```
np.einsum("tvs,tvs->tvv", M_np, M_np).shape
```

I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-139-6de24a454f50> in <module>
      3 
      4 
----> 5 np.einsum("tvs,tvs->tvv", M_np, M_np).shape

<__array_function__ internals> in einsum(*args, **kwargs)

~/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/einsumfunc.py in einsum(out, optimize, *operands, **kwargs)
   1359         if specified_out:
   1360             kwargs['out'] = out
-> 1361         return c_einsum(*operands, **kwargs)
   1362 
   1363     # Check the kwargs to avoid a more cryptic error later, without having to

ValueError: einstein sum subscripts string includes output subscript 'v' multiple times
```

Is it possible to use np.einsum for the above operation?

Comment: "tvs,tws->tvw" should do it.  It's complaining about the `tvv`.  That the size of `v` and `w` is the same doesn't affect the multiplication.